# If I have signed representation in assembly should I always use `imul` and `idiv`?

Tags: assembly, x86

`imul` and `idiv` works exactly the same like `mul` and `div`. So is it just a convention to use it with **signed integers**?

Comment: No, they don't work the same for signed values, so you should indeed be using them if that's your scenario.

Comment: Note that what @500-InternalServerError says only applies to the one operand form of `imul` and `idiv`.  The two and three operand forms of `imul` apply to signed and unsigned numbers equally.